# how can i use date diff in oracle. I need no of days how can i achieve this

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this. I need to use date diff im new to oracle. How can i find no of days in oracle.

**Sql**

```
SELECT * FROM TICKETS WHERE SUBMITTED_ON-1
```

**Tickets Table**

```
TICKET_ID |SUBJECT                     |CHANGE_TYPE |PRIORITY |SUBMITTED_ON        
----------|----------------------------|------------|---------|--------------------
343       |Test CR child 123           |4           |4        |2015-06-11 08:24:17 
345       |New test today              |2           |3        |2015-06-11 08:45:16 
352       |CR for child ticket purpose |2           |4        |2015-06-15 04:53:26
```

How to find the date differnce btween SUBMITTED_ON - CURRENT DATE with no of days ?

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: what do you mean `SUBMITTED_ON-1` ? what is your desired output?

Comment: pls chck the updated question

Comment: submitted_on - SYSDATE gives the difference in days (a difference of 4.75 means four days and 18 hours, 0.75 * 24 hours = 18 hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would subtract them and use `trunc()` to remove the time component.  Depending on what you want, this is either:

```
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(sysdate) - TRUNC(submitted_on)
FROM TICKETS t;
```

or:

```
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(sysdate - submitted_on)
FROM TICKETS t;
```

Note:  This appears to be the answer to your question.  But if you want to test the values in the `WHERE` clause, then Matthew's answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can just subtract two dates in Oracle and the answer will be the difference between them, in days.  So, 1.5 would be 1.5 days (or 36 hours).

For example, you could write

```
SELECT * FROM TICKETS WHERE SUBMITTED_ON >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
```

And it would give you all the tickets submittted on or after the beginning of the day yesterday, because `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` is the beginning of the current day and `TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1` is the beginning of yesterday.

To get the age of each ticket, you would write

```
SELECT SYSDATE - SUBMITTED_ON FROM TICKETS
```

You'd `round()` that or `trunc()` or leave it as is, depending on what you wanted to do with partial days.

Comment: how to find the current date - SUBMITTED_ ON in oracle ? Pls check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select trunc(SUBMITTED_ON)-trunc(SYSDATE) noofdays from TICKETS
```